# What's the best way to play rtmp stream using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, rtmp

I'm trying to play VOD rtmp stream in angularjs. The streaming server is Wowza and there are players like flowplayer to handle it in a non-angular way.
But what is the best way to play rtmp stream using angularjs?

Comment: angularjs is not a thing to do this. you can wrap any solution for streaming into angularjs

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any wrapped solution for streaming into angularjs?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own plugin to play RTMP, this is relatively easy and you have a few [open source plugins](https://github.com/2fdevs/videogular/tree/master/app/scripts/com/2fdevs/videogular/plugins) to inspire yourself.

Take a look to [this Youtube plugin](https://github.com/NamPNQ/bower-videogular-youtube), because it is very similar to what you need to do, but instead inject a Youtube player, you need to inject a Flash player. You can use [Video.js](http://www.videojs.com/), [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/), [JWPlayer](http://www.jwplayer.com/) or [OSMF](http://osmf.org/strobe_mediaplayback.html) for RTMP streaming, any solution is a good approach so just take the video player that feels more comfy for you.

Comment: By the way, there's also a Flash fallback plugin, so you only need to use a Flash player to play your RTMP. https://github.com/NamPNQ/bower-videogular-flash

Answer (score 1):

here is a mediaPlayer directive that works with many media libraries. It is template based, so you can create RTMP templates based upon the chosen library.

https://github.com/joshkurz/Black-Belt-AngularJS-Directives/tree/master/directives/mediaPlayer

Currently have it working with

- mediaelement.js
- flowplayer.js
- pure HTML5

[Demo](http://angulardirectives.joshkurz.net/dist/#/mediaelement)

Answer (score 0):

[Videogular](https://github.com/2fdevs/videogular) is an HTML5 video player for AngularJS. It has a public API that is extensible through plugins. HTML5 does not support RTMP though. But similarly to what @STEVER suggested, you can wrap a non-HTML5, flash-based streaming solution (for instance [Video.js RTMP](http://blog.videojs.com/post/60471080014/video-js-4-2-0-released-rtmp-css-designer-and)) into AngularJS to perhaps get a streaming plugin for Videogular.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In case I just need streaming video, should I write a plugin for Videogular or use Video.js instead?

Comment: What about if streaming from an S3 bucket? Can that be done with Videogular?